# numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statsmodels

Here are my numpy arrays:

```
z 
[[  3.90311860e-322   1.83939721e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.83939721e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   9.96473555e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.83939721e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.03585447e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.83939721e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.83939721e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   9.41400244e-001]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.01817846e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   1.83939721e-001]]
weights
[[ -1.76457791 -24.11966074]
 [ -2.69231436 -24.11966074]
 [-24.11966074  -2.0106293 ]
 [ -1.99135789 -24.11966074]
 [-24.11966074  -1.89735781]
 [ -2.01441034 -24.11966074]
 [ -2.37736986 -24.11966074]
 [-24.11966074  -2.19061707]
 [-24.11966074  -1.94675704]
 [ -1.5983523  -24.11966074]]
X
[[   0.     2.5  100. ]
 [   2.     5.    80. ]
 [  31.    50.   -11. ]
 [  -0.5    2.    90. ]
 [  30.    45.5  -11. ]
 [   1.5    2.5  101. ]
 [   1.2    4.    85. ]
 [  31.    52.   -10. ]
 [  30.    48.   -15. ]
 [   1.     2.5  113. ]]
```

When I do

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

    for y1, w in zip(z.T, weights.T): # building the parameters per j class
        temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, X, w).fit()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c.py", line 177, in <module>
    boost(X, y, 10, test3)
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c.py", line 80, in boost
    temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, X, w).fit()  # Step 2(a)(ii)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 127, in fit
    self.pinv_wexog = pinv_wexog = np.linalg.pinv(self.wexog)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1574, in pinv
    u, s, vt = svd(a, 0)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1323, in svd
    raise LinAlgError('SVD did not converge')
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What does `weights` mean?

Comment: Is it normalized as 1/w?

Comment: yes, weights are initially normalized as 1/w, but I've pasted them here *just* before they go into statsmodels.WLS, and by that time they've been changed.

Comment: Did you try `sm.WLS(y1, X, w/w.sum()).fit()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The weights aren't normalized in the model in any way. You passed negative weights and as the docstring says, the sqrt of weights is used. This introduces NaNs, which is usually what the SVD convergence failure indicates.

Comment: oh I see... in other words I you're saying that I should:
(1) normalize my weights and then
(2) use their squares...
Is that right?

Comment: Whether you want to normalize is up to you, but you can't input negative weights.